# I need to write a C program that adds two numbers each of 100+ digits?

Tags: c

Need to write a C program that adds two numbers each of 100+ digits..

I don't want the method of using arrays to do this.
Please suggest me how to store this numbers(atleast of 512 bit sized) and do the arithmetic operations?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3695992/1870232

Comment: Yeah, an assignment, has to be.

Answer (score 5):

You could use an *arbitrary precision arithmetic* library, such as [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) for that.

A quick C example:

```
#include <gmp.h>

mpz_t a, b;

const char *huge_decimal_num1 = "46819294521564960351683095841209562359068";
const char *huge_decimal_num2 = "6904120584864540916814056801234572451249681";

mpz_init_set_str (a, huge_decimal_num1, 10);    
mpz_init_set_str (b, huge_decimal_num2, 10);    
mpz_add (a, a, b); // a = a + b

printf("%s + %s = %s\n", 
 huge_decimal_num1, huge_decimal_num2, mpz_get_str (NULL, 10, a));
```